# Rails PostGIS ActiveRecord Adapter sometimes returns string instead of RGeo::Geos::CAPIPointImpl object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, postgis

I am using the `PostGIS ActiveRecord Adapter` in a Rails API app. I have a DB table called `events` where one of the columns is a PostGIS geometry column called `coordinates` e.g.:

```
create_table 'events' do |t|
  t.geometry 'coordinates;
end
```

When a user queries my API, I use `Netflix's Fast JSON API` to serialize my response:

```
class EventSerializer
  include FastJsonapi::ObjectSerializer

    attribute :coordinates do |object|
      # coincidentally my column name and PostGIS Adapters method for getting the coordinates is the same 
      object.coordinates.coordinates
    end
end
```

Now most of the time the above works and I get a response that has the coordinates, but every now and then I will get the following error:

```
'undefined method coordinates for "0101000020E610000061C3D32B65965DC03657CD7344F64040" String, did you mean codepoints'
```

The above happens sporadically and I cannot recreate it since most of the time everything works fine. And by fine I mean I only have 5 records in the database and if execute the same function that ultimately serializers the 5 records, it will work 50 times but then 1 time it will give me the error above and keep giving me the error above in subsequent calls. I then restart the server and all goes back to normal.

My best guess is that the serializer is processing the object faster than the adapter is parsing the RGeo object to return the coordinates, but I am not sure how to fix that.

Anyone have any solutions?

Comment: Can you try and log the type of object.coordinates and trigger the error? I'm guessing it's a data issue and something is being returned that you're not expecting.

Comment: @sevensidedmarble that’s just the thing. I stop the execution of the code using byebug and I test each object passed to the serializer. When I do this and I test each object, I get no errors and I don’t get any errors in any subsequent requests. It only happens when the code is executed without any debugging, which is what makes me think there is a race condition somewhere.

Comment: Have you tried doing it with a different serializer like jbuilder just as a test?

Comment: @sevensidedmarble not yet. I’m stubborn and trying to at least find where the bug originates :) but if i can’t figure it out then I might use a different serializer to identify if it’s the sterilizer or active record. The only issue is that because it happens infrequently, I might switch to a different sterilizer and nothing will happen for a while, giving me a false positive.

Comment: Yeah but determining if it happens in only one serializer could tell you where to start looking at least. Could be a bug in the serializer instead of your end...

Comment: Hi @Darkisa, did you ever find a solution? We're facing the same issue here, geoms randomly loaded as strings. Doesn't depend on the geom or anything.

Comment: I did not but after upgrading my rails to version 6, the problem seems to have gone away.